# How can I avoid having history rewritten when I push my changes?

Tags: git, gitlab

My general workflow is to git commit, then git pull, then git push.

I've found that if there are new changes (from other people) that had happened since my last push, it merges them into my branch when I do the commit, and this shows up in the git (gitlab) history and kind-of looks like changes I've made.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or a simple way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the merge, use `git pull --rebase` instead of `git pull`. This will, instead of merging any new commits from `origin` into your own branch, rebase your changes onto theirs. Everything will then look like (and be, actually) a linear history.

Unless you apply the `-f` option during `git push`, git will not allow you to rewrite.